# My app crashes on some devices error is Caused by android.view.InflateException Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView

Tags: java, android

My app is crashing on some devices my minimum API level is set to 16 and when i am testing my app on different devices then its crashing without any detailed error below is details of error

**Error:**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cbcwebs.app.wincoin/com.cbcwebs.app.wincoin.SplashScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView

On line Number 32 on My Splash Screen Class 
and **this is line one 32** `(setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);)`

**My Activity Code**

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
        }



        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser == null) {

            List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(

                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build());


            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                             .setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
                            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                            .build(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN);


        }else {


           checkUserExist();




        }
```

**and My Layout XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashScreen">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="186dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.421"
        android:src="@drawable/wincoin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/wincoin" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Full Error**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cbcwebs.app.wincoin/com.cbcwebs.app.wincoin.SplashScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.cbcwebs.app.wincoin, PID: 11121
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cbcwebs.app.wincoin/com.cbcwebs.app.wincoin.SplashScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.cbcwebs.app.wincoin.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:32)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0800ec a=-1 r=0x7f0800ec}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2068)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:71)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:67)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:181)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:105)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Please post the entire Java stack trace, not just the error message.

Comment: can you share the wincoin image

Comment: its a normal PNG image in android its showing linke this => wincoin.png(V24)

Comment: is it something with this bracket (v24)?

Answer (score 2):

Use `app:srcCompat="@drawable/wincoin"`  instead of  `android:src="@drawable/wincoin"` in your **ImageView** layout in all Layout files.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem my app would crash on older versions of android. and was getting
android.view.Inflateexception, after some searches found that my drawable had only v24 files, and was not supporting older API versions, I solved it by creating new drawable resource file with the same file name that of the v24 files, Android studio automatically create a folder and move both files to that folder. 
Next step just copy data from v24 files and paste it in the file without v24 files.
Thats it.